# Minecraft says "servers are down for maintenance"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to join a server it says:

> Failed to connect to server                Failed to login: The authentication servers are currently down for maintenance.

YES, I have checked if they were down but they are not! When I try to make my own lan server or singleplayer my skin is slim alex. But what is wierd is I can only join cracked servers. This is my account I got it in 2010. This only happens on this computer on any router.

What can I do about it?

EDIT:

I have reinstalled minecraft before and I had nothing no mods or optifine. my computer is an Alienware 13 R3 16GB of ram Windows 10 Home Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHZ.  my minecraft is vannila, and my java is up to date.

EDIT2: I have found out that I have a proxy called covernant eyes. And when I try to uninstall it the uninstaller crashes. Whelp.

Comment: If the servers are indeed not down, as the OP claims, then the suggested duplicate is no duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Arqade, It would be helpful if you could specify more information about your computer/router - Computer specs, ethernet/wifi etc. Also, please include any troubleshooting you have already done, so it is not a "Do it for me" question.

First, ensure you are running a completely vanilla version of minecraft. Forge/optifine are known to cause this problem every now and then.

If this doesn't work, you could have a corrupt install of Minecraft

A quick google search comes up with instructions to reinstall.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Minecraft_help_FAQ#Reinstalling_Minecraft

If that doesn't help, ensure your java is up to date.

Feel free to ask for more help if this doesn't work.